# How to send server request after 7 days completed?

Tags: android

I have an app in if user keep my app in their device for 7 days Then I have to send server request after 7 days whether user launch app or not.How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlaramManager to set repeating alarm for every 7 days. When alarm will trigger, you can execute the request to get data from the server. See further at:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html